# How to show Low Events dates in a Postmaster parcel

Tags: postmaster, low-events

How can I get a Low Events date to display in a Postmaster parcel? I want to send an email confirmation when a user submits an upcoming training session announcement.

1.) I tried this:

```
{parcel:training_event_details}
```

2.) I tried this:

```
{parcel:training_event_details:start_date}
```

3.) I tried this (a combination of [this example from Low](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-events/docs/fieldtype) and [this example from Objective HTML](https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster/parcels)):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="training_sessions" entry_id="{parcel:entry_id}" dynamic="no" status="not closed"}
  {training_event_details:start_date format="%j %F %Y"}{training_event_details:start_time format=", %H:%i"}
  {if training_event_details:one_day == 'y'}
    {training_event_details:end_time format="&ndash; %H:%i"}
  {if:else}
    &mdash;
    {training_event_details:end_date format="%j %F %Y"}{training_event_details:end_time format=", %H:%i"}
  {/if}
  ({training_event_details:duration})
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

All methods above render blank. What am I missing? Thanks!

Versions:

- ExpressionEngine: 2.9.2
- Low Events: 1.3.1
- Postmaster: 1.5.0

**Edit to fix bug (mentioned by Low in comment) in code #3:**

Here is the working code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="training_sessions" entry_id="{parcel:entry_id}" dynamic="no" status="not closed"}
  {training_event_details:start_date format="%j %F %Y"}{training_event_details:start_time format=", %H:%i"}
  {if '{training_event_details:one_day}' == 'y'}
    {training_event_details:end_time format="&ndash; %H:%i"}
  {if:else}
    &mdash;
    {training_event_details:end_date format="%j %F %Y"}{training_event_details:end_time format=", %H:%i"}
  {/if}
  ({training_event_details:duration})
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Postmaster, so can't really comment on that. All I know is that, looking at the conditional, you might be encountering this EE bug: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20621/variables-with-modifiers-not-working-in-conditionals-without-braces -- although that's probably unrelated to the issue.

Comment: Good point. I'll fix that in my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so method #3 in my question above actually DOES work. It didn't preview correctly for the entry I was looking at but when I changed to several other entries it rendered fine. There was something goofed up with that particular entry and I've since deleted it. Anyway, sorry to waste your time, Low!